# Where statement is not capturing my condition correctly

Tags: sas, data-manipulation, analysis

I want to tell SAS to capture specific observation under the variable "rashloc_spcy" (and others) for a string observations ("B", "P/G", "Peri", "Gen"). However, when I see the results, SAS is capturing other observations not described in my statement. Is there anything I can do to modify my code?

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwVNq.jpg)

```
proc print data=k.dataset;
var rashloc_GNT rashloc_PER rasloc_Spcfy;
where ((rashloc_GNT = "GNT") OR (rashloc_PER = "PER")) OR rashloc_Spcfy in ("B", "P/G", "Peri", "Gen"));
run;
```

I should be getting only the quoted keyterms in the variable of interest (rashloc_spcfy)

Comment: Imgur link is broken. Your last statement is incorrect because you're also looking at rashloc_GNT unless you want that condition to be AND rather than OR.

Comment: The link is active for me. Please correct me if I am wrong, because the correct statement would be "OR" if I want to find any observations has "GNT", "PER", "B", "P/G", "Peri", "Gen". If I include the 'AND' statement wouldn't that tell SAS to include and satisfy all the observations statement (in other words having a higher criteria search/condition).

Comment: Code doesn't match image( variable names so making a guess) but for the record highlighted assuming that your second OR condition is what includes that record. it has the PER in the second column. So it matches the code.

Comment: Anyways, please include your data as text not images. If we want to write any code to assist we'd have to type out your data and thats more work for someone to do.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to exclude cases where the third variable is some other non missing value if they meet the first two criteria?

So perhaps?

```
where ((rashloc_GNT = "GNT") OR (rashloc_PER = "PER"))
  and not (rashloc_Spcfy not in (" ","B","P/G","Peri","Gen")) 
;
```